# Legalities of modifying Ubuntu MOTD

Tags: legal, ubuntu

I made few modifications to few specific Ubuntu files for showing my own custom messages in place of Ubuntu specific messages. For this, I have made changes to following files:

```
/etc/update-motd.d/00-header
/etc/update-motd.d/10-help-text
/etc/legal
/etc/os-release
/etc/lsb-release
/etc/dpkg/origins/default
/etc/issue
/etc/issue.net
/proc/version
```

According to my research, there should not be any issue in modifying the /etc/update-motd.d/* files. However, I am not sure about rest of the files, especially /etc/legal file.

My question is that whether it is permissible to modify the above files? Is there any legal obligations which I need to respect? Any help will be highly appreciated :).

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This changes tremendously depending on whether or not you distribute your modifications or keep them to yourself.

Comment: What is it you want that stock ubuntu doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Different parts of Ubuntu are licensed under different conditions. But according to [the Ubuntu licensing page](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing), one condition for being included into Ubuntu is a free license which allows the end-user to make modifications.

However, when you redistribute your changed version to other people, you need to follow the license conditions of each component. This usually means that you must not change any copyright messages and license files.

Comment: Thanks Phillipp for your prompt answer.
What if I want to redistribute my changed version to my customer? Is it permissible?

Comment: So, let me rephrase my question. You are saying that different parts are licensed under different conditions. So, my question is that under which license, the files which I have mentioned, fall?
Is it permissible to modify above mentioned files and still redistribute the version safely?

Thanks for your help... :)